# How to programmatically collapse Access Stripe Commands and Navigation Pannel?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

How to programmatically collapse Access Stripe Commands and Navigation Pannel?
I've been trying to do it with `Application.SetOption` but I couldn't find the right option. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stripe means the Ribbon, try this:

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

To close the navigation panel, try this:

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

Comment: very good, where did you find this information? I think that it's not in vb help...

Comment: I found it quickly by searching my code library.  I don't remember where I found it originally ... it may have been from reading the  *comp.databases.ms-access* newsgroup.  Anyway, I'm pleased it was useful to you.  :-)